# Is fitting a model in a for loop equivalent to using epochs>1?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, epochs

I'm using tensorflow to train a network to do an image segmentation task, and I have a question about the behavior of `model.fit` between epochs, specifically:

**Is there any difference between calling `model.fit` with 512 epochs, and calling `model.fit` 512 times?**

Here's a simplified version of my code, in case it helps. First, some setup:

```
# Create image generators for dataset augmentation
imgGen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_augmentation_parameters)
maskGen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_augmentation_parameters)
seed = random.randint(0, 1000000000)
imgIterator = imgGen.flow(img, seed=seed, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
maskIterator = maskGen.flow(mask, seed=seed, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

# Load network structure from model.py file
network = unet(net_scale = 1)

# Calculate # of iterations
steps_per_epoch = int(num_samples / batch_size)
```

The two methods of iteratively fitting:

Fit method #1:

```
network.fit(
    ((imgBatch, maskBatch) for imgBatch, maskBatch in zip(imgIterator, maskIterator)),
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=512,
)
```

Fit method #2:

```
for epoch in range(512):
    network.fit(
        ((imgBatch, maskBatch) for imgBatch, maskBatch in zip(imgIterator, maskIterator)),
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        epochs=1,
    )
```

I think [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/82113/how-to-train-the-model-with-for-loop-instead-of-the-built-in-epochs) is the same as mine, but I don't understand how the one answer applies to the question - I simply want to know if there is some internal difference between specifying an epoch number > 1 and running `model.fit` in a for loop.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4446#issuecomment-261804574) question in the github repository for Keras, yes you should be able to incrementally train your model the way you want in a loop. That being said, you should likely run a test on both ways and see if it yields different results.